# Transparent layer over img when hover ++ text

Tags: html, css, image

I want to add an transparent layer over my img on a card when I hover over it, I have done that part but I want it to be cut to the img and not cover the footer on the card. If that makes sence?

this is the card with Hover. As u can see on the card, the img just covers like 90% of the card, I want the hover overlay to do the same

[Card when not hover IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRB3k.jpg)
[Card when hover IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXQ54.png)

```
   .card {
   position:relative;
   width: 350px;
   height: 335px;
   background-size: contain;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-color: #fff;
   border-radius: 5px;
   margin: 30px;
   float: left;
   }

   #card_oslo{
   background-image: url(img/oslo.jpg);
   }
   #card_oslo:hover{
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
   transition: .5s;
   }
```

Comment: I also would like to get text to appere when I hover over the card, thats the point of the dark transparency layer. Any suggestions to how to do that? thx

Comment: We need to see the markup as well, so we can suggest a good approach

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) for this. Use [`:after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) or [`:before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) and set it as full size also set the parent with `position:relative;` then change the `opacity` of the pseudo element on `hover`.

Working [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/dknzx072/3/).

```css
.box {
  position:relative;
}
.box:after {
  content:"";
  /* Set the element as full-size */
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  /* Set bg and hide the element + animation */
  background-color:#000;
  opacity:0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}
.box:hover:after {
  /* Show the overlay on hover */
  opacity:0.5;
}

/* For the demo */
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the overlay to

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: XXpx;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

where XX is the footer height, then it will cover the whole card and leave the bottom x pixels free. You can also use % values instead of px.

If you want the overlay to contain text you need to put it into an extra div that you can then use as overlay.

I made a simplified version here https://jsfiddle.net/0L9fL1pj/

Comment: Read the question again

Comment: yeah I just realized it's what he has not what he wants

Comment: Give the overlay width 350, height 335, and border radius 5px. Then it will be the same size as the image. Then you can position it absolutely and it should be in the right place.

Comment: @RunnyYolk That is the same size as the card if you check the question's CSS

Answer (score 0):

Been looking for a similar solution and since this thread never got a proper answer (neither proposed answer got me where I wanted and I doubt) but I got some important clues here and I thought I'd provide my current solution so anyone who has a similar problem can benefit.

I made a simple demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/Tdesign/2ynuajk0/14/

HTML:

```
<div id="imgBox2" class="shade">
        <img id="img2" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/Gull_portrait_ca_usa.jpg" width="350" height="335" loading="lazy" >
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    #imgBox2 {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
}

    .shade:hover::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```